# puppet server failing to install on centos 9 stream

Tags: puppetmaster, centos9

I tried installing puppetserver on my centos 9 stream but it gives me the following error:

> Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:42 ago on Thu 23 Feb 2023
> 01:06:09 AM EST. No match for argument: puppetserver Error: Unable to
> find a match: puppetserver

I downloaded the following rpm:

```
yum install https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet-release-el-9.noarch.rpm -y
```

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 9 is not listed as a [supported OS for the Puppet server](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/server/install_from_packages.html#supported-operating-systems).

It is only listed as a [supported OS for the Puppet agent](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/system_requirements.html#supported_operating_systems-packaged-platforms).

The server most probably is not available on the el-9 repo.

---

You can [install it from source](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/server/dev_running_from_source.html), it will however be more difficult to get support for it. It is preferable to use a supported OS instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Ruby: Puppet is written in Ruby, so you'll need to install a
  Ruby interpreter. You can do this using the package manager by
  running the command:

  sudo dnf install ruby
- Install Puppet: Download the Puppet tarball from the Puppet website
  (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/puppet_from_source.html) and
  extract it to a location of your choice.
- Install Puppet dependencies: Install any required dependencies for
  Puppet by running the following command from the directory where you
  extracted the Puppet tarball:

  bundle install --path .vendor
- Set up the environment: Set up the necessary environment variables by
  running the following command:

  export PATH=/bin:$PATH
- Replace  with the path to the directory where you
  extracted the Puppet tarball.
- Verify the installation: Verify that Puppet is installed correctly by
  running the following command:

  puppet --version

This should display the version of Puppet that you just installed.